# Why is map just grayscale mode after using MRT?

Tags: coordinate-system, hdf

[image]

i just follow the step to change .hdf file to geotiff file from this site http://duncanjg.wordpress.com/2012/12/11/loading-modis-ndvi-time-series-into-postgis-raster/#comment-1214

and i use data from http://reverb.echo.nasa.gov/reverb
but, why my tiff just grayscale mode (black white)?

so how can i get color mapping?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a one-band-dataset, it will be displayed as grayscale as default.

You can change that to any kind of pseudocolour, depending on the software you use.

To get real colours, you need either 3 band data with red-green-blue colour interpretation, or paletted colours.